# Shopify: How can I limit a product to 1 per customer?

Tags: shopify

Looking for a straight forward way to limit my **free sample** product to be able to be bought 1 time per registered customer **without using any promo/discount code**.

I was thinking to maybe store a note for the customer and reference it, but I found that you can't access notes so easily.

EDIT: Seems like I can access all the orders through **customer.orders**. Is it feasible to iterate through the orders and then transactions and products and see if the product id matches the free sample id, and if so, prevent the user from accessing the free sample product in my `.liquid` template files?

Comment: Did you think of tagging the customer with let's say free-sample once he has already ordered your free sample? If you can accomplish this, then you can do the following on product.liquid unless customer.tag == free-sample -->show ad to cart button endunless another unless will be needed to make sure you're applying this logic only to the free-sample product page.

Comment: How can you tag the customer post checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than creating a formal app you can create a private app and call it with a web hook. The web hook would inspect the order for your sample product and then tag the order's customer.

As far as infrastructure you'd need a place where you can run and install a secure app (I'd use Node). If you don't already have a host with a certificate there are various ways to host. Amazon EC2 is available free for a year.

see

- https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook
- https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/creating-a-private-app
- https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/customer#customer-tags
- https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Sounds like this is the only ideal answer. Just a question: so is creating a customer note not feasible?

Comment: Also - does the private app really necessarily need to be hosted on SSL?

Comment: Probably not. The order hook could just be used to call the app and be limited to non-sensitive info. The app would use https to retrieve order details so no sensitive info would go out over the wire.

Comment: And in my customers/account.liquid I'd just have some code that calls the my app with http://app.com/get-orders?customer_id=2939320&type=free-sample and if the result set is empty, then list it out? And this part doesn't need to be https'd or does it?

Comment: I setup a web hook that gets the JSON on order paid and am storing it in a DB and mark whether there was a free sample or not. Are you saying though that instead of that I can determine on the fly if it was a free sample or not, how would the call look to tag the customer with the API?

Comment: I don't know what your back end scripting language is but a full example using node is here for updating item variants: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164203/uploading-new-products-with-multiple-variant-options/32228006#32228006.   You could just substitute the url for 'customers' instead of products and `{
          customer:{
            id: customerId, 
            tags: 'free-product'
          }
        }` for the payload

Comment: also just a note that if you award the reputation bounty on this you should split it between me and @alexandresaiz. I provided the technical background and references but it was his idea. My first thought would have been to use meta fields which would have been slightly and unnecessarily more complex.

Comment: thanks. also - not sure if i can actually split the bounty. hmm

Answer (score 1):

Write a tiny app which tags (free-sample) all customers who order product x. Then on your product.liquid you need to work some code like:

if product handle == free-product (you make sure the customer is within the product x page)

unless customer.tag == free-sample

SHOW ADD TO CART BUTTON

endunless

endif

Comment: Do you have any specifics on actually tagging the customer during the checkout process?

Comment: How many orders do you envision? Depending on this, you can follow one approach or another.

Comment: this is a small store, maybe under a thousand orders in a year

Comment: If that's 2/3 per day, maybe you want to check your orders which have that product once a week and tag the customers within your Shopify admin dashboard? Othewise you can come up with a tiny script which places the order without forcing the user to pass through the checkout and hitting the API directly, creating the order and tagging the customer? Can you mark my answer as valid?

Comment: I'm just confused on the process of tagging the customer - so this isn't possible through the normal checkout? I have to hit the API directly? There's no way of binding it to the checkout through notes - what about leaving a note for a customer and retrieving a note?

Comment: Not sure if you'll be able to place an order and at the same time store a note to that particular customer. If you could do so, then, you have it.

Comment: what if a customer is not logged in and we have to restrict user to buy  one free sample ?  for login users above ideas seems great.