# Change Color title for all products

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to change the variant title "color" to "flavor".  I've tried to change it in the code but not working.  I have thousands of products and to change Color for each one will be way to much work.  The code where the title color displays is listed below.  Is this even possible?

```
<select name="id" id="productSelect" class="product-variants">
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available %}

      <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>

    {% else %}
      <option disabled="disabled">
        {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
      </option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the Shopify API.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164203/uploading-new-products-with-multiple-variant-options/32228006#32228006) for a fully worked node.js script. It creates a product. for updating the product you'd have to get all your products that have  color as a variant name and run something like:

```
var options = {
  host: 'mydomain.myshopify.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/admin/products/1925263361.json', // per product
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: headers
};
...
var product = {
  product:{
    id:'1925263361',
    options : [ // just update the variant titles; no other fields
      {name : "Bob"}, //was First
      {name : "Carol"}, // was Second
      {name : "Third"}
    ]
    }

};
```